# "Not in" view for 1:N relationships

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Assume we have an entity A which has a 1:N relationship with entity B. I want to create a view, that shows only records of A which has no entity B. A good example is, I want to view Quotes without Order.

Any solution with any complexity would be appreciated, such as plugin, script, silverlight...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to tackle it indirectly one way or another:

1. use a SSRS report and embed that where it would be needed (eg in a dashboard). This would have to use SQL rather than FetchXML, so this could only be a solution for CRM On-Premise, not Online
2. Use a workflow or plugin on create of record B1, or update of B1's parent lookup to entity A, which updates parent record "A1" with some arbitrary field (eg "date of first Order" or "Is converted to Order"). Now just build a standard advanced find query for new_field contains data, (or = 1 if it is a bit field). Depending on the exact scenario, you might need to actually use an integer count if records of entity B could be routinely deleted, or reparented to a different parent A2, so that you can increment / decrement as appropriate (so a reparent would inc the new one and dec the old).

Edit: Note that in CRM 2013 ("orion"), the FetchXML implementation does support this kind of construction for a view, but the Advanced Find tool (for example) does not provide a UI for it. See the answer to this question for more information:
[View Showing Accounts that don't have contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487235/view-showing-accounts-that-dont-have-contact)

Comment: Hi AdamV, Thanks for your answer. Would you please elaborate the option "1" about sql report? Some links or tutorials about creating the report would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest this is marked as the answer.  You cannot do a query of this complexity in CRM, so it'll either have to be done via a report or using a plugin to update a field which denotes lack of child records, and base a view off this.  CRM does not support aggregate/calculated fields, which is a shame.

Comment: @Payman - where would you like me to start? How you start VS to create a new report project, or what the SQL statements might look like? Either way I think you will find thousands of articles already written on the subject if you care to look. Or start a new question on SO "How do I create a SRRS report for CRM 2011". 
Do you definitely have CRM 2011 on-premise, not Online?

Comment: Thanks AdamV. I have On premise. Im going through it!

Answer (score -1):

Use the **Advanced Find** and Select Quotes, then for the criteria select the Order lookup field
and choose the operator to be **Does Not Contain Data**. By this way, you'll get all records for entity B which have no parents of entity A.

Download the FetchXML and use it in your Plugin or Silverlight.

**Edit:**

I think the best way is to create an N:N relation with manually created intersect table.
And your query has to select target the intersect table.
As you might know, the intersect table links to both Entities A and B.

The criteria will be: selecting Intersect table where there is no reference to Entity B.

Comment: The orders is not a lookup field on the quote!!! The relation of quotes and orders is 1:N! Then, how a quote could have a lookup field of orders????

Comment: You can't use FetchXML to create a "Not in", there is currently no supported syntax for this